# Error: Could not find or load main class Running Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am using Hadoop 2.9.1 standalone (the folder I am using is after successful compilation of the source code) and whenever I run a Hadoop command such as 
(where `$HADOOP_HOME= /usr/local/hadoop`, the directory of hadoop)

```
$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.9.1.jar grep input output 'dfs[a-z.]+'
```

I get this error :

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar

At first, I was thinking that I am missing some environment variables but are they necessary for the standalone case? Why did I get this error? (I even replaced with another example, I believe it is not a jar problem)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the compilation folder I got using maven command :

```
mvn clean package -Pdist -Psrc -DskipTests -Dtar
```

The right one is:

```
mvn clean install -Pdist -Dtar -DskipTests
```